# Unable to undo some symbolic links

Tags: undo-redo

I have the following symbolic link for my `~/.vimrc`

```
~/.vimrc -> ~/Dropbox/Backup/Dotfiles/.vimrc
```

When I edit this file with `vim ~/.vimrc`, I see an `undofile` is created which looks like this:

```
%Users%username%Dropbox%Backup%Dotfiles%.vimrc
```

If I close the file, reopen it, and press undo, I get the following message:

> Already at oldest change

How can I resolve this issue?

P.S. Undo works well for `~/.zshrc`, which is also a symbolic link.

Comment: that can happen for various things, no undo information has been stored, you changed the file externaly, etc. Try `:verbose :rundo <filename>`  and Vim should tell you if there was an error with it

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, thanks for the pointer. I get `File contents changed, cannot use undo info` when I run the command you mentioned, but I didn't change the file externally. I removed the undo file a few times today and only changed my `~/.vimrc` from the terminal to test the undo behavior, but faced the same issue every time.

Comment: I have a hypothesis about why `File contents changed, cannot use undo info` could, in fact, be right. The `~/.vimrc` file is a symbolic link to the actual file on my Dropbox. One of my Macs uses the new Dropbox location, which is under `~/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox` and the other one still uses the old location `~/Dropbox`. This leads to having two different undo files for the `~/.vimrc` file. I suspect if I change the `~/.vimrc` file on one machine, the undo file on the other machine assumes the file is modified externally, which no longer allows undoing.